# Import CA certificate into Chrome via command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, certificate, macos

Is it possible to import a custom Certificate Authority (.crt) using Terminal or over SSH on macOS 10.13 High Sierra?

Answer (score 3):

> In MacOS (High Sierra), is it possible to import a custom Certificate Authority (.crt) using Terminal or over SSH?

Yes, it is.

**Add a certificate with Terminal**

Chrome uses the System keychain certificate store. To add a CA certificate **locally**, launch Terminal and run this command (I've broken it down into several lines to make it more readable, but the command is fully functional):

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert \
-k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
-d /path/to/CAcertificate.crt
```

where:

`sudo` runs the command that follows with administrative privileges (type your login password when requested)

`security` is a utility to manipulate keychains

`-k` specifies which keychain to use (run `security list-keychains` to get a list of available keychains). **Note that new root certificates should be added to the login keychain** for the current user, **or to the System keychain** if they are to be shared by all users of this machine, because the System Roots keychain cannot be modified. In the example above, I use the System keychain.

`-d` adds the certificate to the admin cert store (so that the user doesn't have to authenticate via an authentication dialog)

`/path/to/CAcertificate.crt` is the path to your CA certificate. The command accepts ASCII ([PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions)) and binary ([DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions)) certificates.

(See `man security` for more information.)

**Add a certificate over SSH**

To add a CA certificate **over SSH**, use this command:

```
ssh -t -t <username>@<remote computer> \
'sudo bash -c "security add-trusted-cert \
-k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
-d <(echo \"<your CA certificate in PEM format>\")"'
```

where:

`<your CA certificate in PEM format>` are the contents of `/path/to/CAcertificate.crt` in PEM format (see below for an example).

Note that in this case you will have to type the password of `<username>` twice: once for logging in over `ssh` and once to run `sudo` on the remote system.

**Example**

Before importing your CA certificate, Chrome will display a "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error because the CA certificate is not trusted:

[image]

Let's say you store your CA certificate in `/tmp/SelfSignedCertRootCA.crt` with contents:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Import it **locally** to Chrome with this command:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert \
-k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
-d /tmp/SelfSignedCertRootCA.crt
```

or **over SSH** (in the example below, to a remote system with IP address 172.16.96.141) with this command:

```
ssh -t -t jaume@172.16.96.141 \
'sudo bash -c "security add-trusted-cert \
-k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain \
-d <(echo \"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----\")"'
```

Now reload the site. The error is gone:

[image]

and the certificate is listed in the System keychain:

[image]