# How to import self-signed certificate over SSH? (bounty)

Tags: terminal, ssh, encryption, remote-control, macos

I'm trying to remotely (SSH) import a custom certificate into Firefox and/or Chrome. It looks [a similar question has been asked before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331487/import-ssl-cert-into-chrome-via-command-line), but didn't get an answer. I put a 150 point bounty on it in hopes of someone being motivated to answer it. This is a work-related thing, so I could really use some help. The cert I created with done [like so](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04):

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
```

I'm basically trying to import and fully trust the cert using Terminal. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few ways you can do it easiest way would be to get a chrome Dev browser and then connect the two users together with separate names you encrypted the certificate as you clear using Firefox tabs in Chrome Dev